# grails/groovy and wslite - how to make the static XML dynamic?

Tags: xml, grails, soap, groovy

using the grails ws-lite 0.7.2.0, you specify an XML message to be sent via soap thusly:

```
  def response = send(SOAPAction: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
  body {
     GetMothersDay(xmlns: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
        year(2011)
     }
  }
}
```

What I need to do, is replace one of the static elements, e.g. "GetMothersDay" with a dynamic variable, e.g:

```
String action = "GetMothersDay"
def response = send(SOAPAction: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
  body {
     $action(xmlns: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
        year(2011)
     }
  }
}
```

Obviously the above code wont work, but hopefully it illustrates what I am trying to do.

As a bonus question, what is that stuff which is in the outer {}?  Are they function definitions?  e.g. what is "year(2011)", it cant be a function definition and a function call at the same time?

The actual XML messages i need to replace bits of are much longer and more complicated - but essentially the same for each call.

Any help greatly appreciated - if there is no way to do this, I am faced with many hundreds of lines of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$action`, use `"$action"`, or `"${action}"` if the expression is more complex than one variable and has spaces or other problematic characters.

These are method calls, and that's typically how Groovy DSLs/builders work. They're obviously not valid methods, but a method-missing / property-missing handler is active and as long as the methods you're calling are valid for the DSL, they'll be converted into what you're trying to build. Typically the name and/or the args of the method calls are used as data and to determine if the calls are valid.

For the regular `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` (e.g. [in this example](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder)), the methods that include a Map argument become elements with the name derived from the method name, and the Map items become attributes, e.g.

```
car(name:'P50', make:'Peel', year:1962)
```

to

```
<car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'>
```

Methods calls with a String arg become elements with a String body, e.g.

```
country('Isle of Man')
```

becomes

```
<country>Isle of Man</country>
```

You can see in [the source of SOAPMessageBuilder.groovy](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/7d185c49e045927e8ac00ed384f8f55cfec6f36a/src/main/groovy/wslite/soap/SOAPMessageBuilder.groovy) that the closure's `delegate` is set to the builder so it can process the calls, and it uses a `MarkupBuilder` to generate the XML string.

[Programming Groovy 2](https://pragprog.com/book/vslg2/programming-groovy-2) has particularly good coverage of creating DSLs in Groovy.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  so year(2011) is short hand for something like "void year(int year) {}; year(2011)".

Comment: Right, but it'd be a little more relaxed, more like `void year(year) {}` and use `year.toString()` as the body text. The generator would typically allow and generate invalid content, and later the parser would complain about `<year>purple</year>`